# URL issue after migrating to dev site

Tags: urls

I recently migrated a live wordpress site, watershedgeo.com, over to a development site using the temp url, http://vps3813.inmotionhosting.com/~watershedgeo/dev.watershedgeo.com/.

I finally got it launched but the images and links don't show, they're all broken, but a lot of the images are showing their alt text. Here's the weird thing:

If I inspect the images in chrome, they show the temp url as the src of the image, but if I change the root before wp-content to watershedgeo.com, they show up. However, if I inspect the images on the live site, they show the source as http://1qy8tt40p7n9v7tao3knw537.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/imageName

Is there a plugin or a way that I can change it so all the images use 1qy8tt40p7n9v7tao3knw537.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com as the root so the images can show for development? All folders match, it's just the root that needs to be changed

The temp url is what is in the site url for the database and the wp-config.php file.

Comment: The real question is what are the image URLs in the database? Have you got access to PHPmyAdmin or can you connect to the database with SQLYog?

Comment: Yes I'm in phpmyadmin. WOuld this be the GUID in wp_posts, or somewhere else?

Comment: Look at one of the posts with this issue, get the post ID from the wp-admin and then go to the wp_posts table, copy the text from the wp_content field and paste it into a text editor. Once you've done that you should be able to see where wordpress expects the images to be. Then you can use a find & replace tool to update those references

Comment: But it's not just for posts, it's just general images on the home page. even the logo

Comment: For instance, it's looking for an image at http://vps3813.inmotionhosting.com/~watershedgeo/dev.watershedgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016 but if I change the src on the front end with chrome inspector and replace everything before wp-content with 'watershedgeo.com' the image shows up

Comment: Have you checked permissions on wp-content directory to make sure it's accessible? Here's a sample image link, it should work but isn't loading, permissions would block it from loading:     http://vps3813.inmotionhosting.com/~watershedgeo/dev.watershedgeo.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/WSGeo_Logo.png

Comment: Also your hosting provider Inmotion has instructions here for duplicating a site and getting it running: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/duplicate-wordpress-site-for-testing it mentions using a subdomain url; I reckon there's also a nicer test url for you to use, but I haven't found it yet in the docs.

Comment: We had actually originally used the subdomain url but the client doesn't have it registered with their domain registrar so we can't point it to inmotion

Comment: Also, I'm checking permissions now. For that folder they are 775

Comment: I just changed the img src link in one of my wordpress page builders to make the root watershedgeo.com and that worked. Is there a way to mass change urls linked in pages like that? I'm using avada and it's builder

Comment: You can point your own url to it for now and use your own subdomain, but see my answer below, the Inmotion docs has the answer you need. You'll need to run queries, so not a super simple process.

Comment: I use this tool to replace URLs when migrating WordPress sites, it takes care of the serialisation that WordPress uses for widgets and other data. It’s free and easy to use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use phpMyAdmin to dig into the database to change things, I always use the WP Clone plugin to easily move a site from development to production. Install the plugin on both source and target systems, then backup the source, and restore to the target. It's here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ .

Everything is moved for you, with URL adjustments, and other stuff done for you. Easy peasy.

Of course, you can do it more 'manually', but the plugin works well and fast for me (being somewhat lazy).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer on their doc site, "[Correcting Image Links After Migration](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/migrating-wordpress-inmotion-hosting/correct-image-links)":

Here's my copy and paste of the post, but you're better off reading the original post I linked to above.

> Log into your cPanel interface. Select phpmyadmin toolOnce inside the
>   cPanel, find the Databases category and click on the phpMyAdmin tool
>   icon. select new databaseYou are now on the main phpMyAdmin page. Find
>   the newly added database and click on its name from the left-hand
>   sidebar. Our sample database is named testdb.
>
> Select database tableThis opens the database and the screen refreshes
>   with a list of the tables. Using the sidebar again, find and click on
>   the wp-posts table.
>
> Click the SQL buttonLook to the top of the screen and you will see
>   several tabs that run across the page. Click on the SQL tab. enter the
>   SQL code and run it
>
> You are now on a MySQL editor screen. In the code area, copy the
>   following bit of MySQL.
>
> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content, '',''));
>
> Be sure to replace  with the old sitename and  with
>   the new site name. For instance, our original site was
>   inmotiontesting.com and the new test site will be at
>   test.inmotiontesting.com so the code should appear as below:
>
> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=(REPLACE (post_content,
>   'inmotiontesting.com','test.inmotiontesting.com'));
>
> Click on the Go button to run the code and change the URLs for all
>   images in the posts. This will also affect any other 'hard coded'
>   links that were in the posts that pointed to the original site.
>
> Below are before and after shots of the changes made. Note that the
>   image paths are displayed in the lower left hand corners of the
>   images. You can see how they switched to the new sitename after the
>   SQL code ran.

Comment: I had done this previously per their documentation but it didn't help with the images themselves because not all are in posts. A lot of the images are linked directly in the page builder for Avada theme in wordpress > pages

Comment: I see. I've used Avada theme, do their docs provide any help?

Comment: Years ago they recommended exporting it and updating all links there, then reimporting it to the db. Seems clunky, but could work: https://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/problems-moving-wordpress-domain-url-images-post-portfolio/

Comment: Also have you done any of these steps? http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-introduction/installing-wordpress-using-your-temporary-url so you can use the temporary url? Don't do it, probably best bet is to edit the urls out of the database, but I just want to check what else you may have done.

Comment: Nice! The site's images are now loading.